# log returns (almost) same as percent change

Tags: percentage, logarithm

I have this function to calculate log of returns. It works as expected.

```
def log_returns(prices):
    return np.log(prices / prices.shift(1))

data.apply(lambda x: log_returns(x))
```

The values returned are very close to pct_change method. Is this expected?

> data.pct_change()

Comment: For small `x`, it holds that `x` is approximately equal to `log(1+x)`, so yes, that is expected if the percentages are not that large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, for small variations in the natural log are almost equal to percentage change, that's not a code issue.

Since :

```
log(A/B) = log(A) - log(B)
```

and in your case, A is equal to some small change `e` of B.

```
log(A/B) = log(A) - log(B) =  log(B(1+e)) - log(B)
log(A/B) = log(B) + log((1+e)) - log(B) = log(1+e)
```

For small values of `e`, meaning that the `log` is a good approx. around 1

```
log(1+e) ≈ e
```

For a more mathy explanation, see [this SO post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244199/why-is-it-that-natural-log-changes-are-percentage-changes-what-is-about-logs-th).

See for yourself with this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

small = np.linspace(0.01, 0.1, 100)

df = pd.DataFrame({"vals" : small})

df["changes"] = df["vals"].pct_change()

df["log div"] = np.log(df["vals"]/df["vals"].shift())

diff_log = np.log(df["vals"]) - np.log(df["vals"].shift())

df["diff log"] = diff_log

diff_log = diff_log[~np.isnan(diff_log)]

log_div  = df["log div"].dropna().values

assert(np.allclose(log_div, diff_log))
```

and `df.head(10)`:

```
     values   changes   log div  diff log                                                                               
0  0.010000       NaN       NaN       NaN                                                                               
1  0.010909  0.090909  0.087011  0.087011                                                                               
2  0.011818  0.083333  0.080043  0.080043                                                                               
3  0.012727  0.076923  0.074108  0.074108                                                                               
4  0.013636  0.071429  0.068993  0.068993                                                                               
5  0.014545  0.066667  0.064539  0.064539                                                                               
6  0.015455  0.062500  0.060625  0.060625                                                                               
7  0.016364  0.058824  0.057158  0.057158                                                                                  
8  0.017273  0.055556  0.054067  0.054067                                                                                    
9  0.018182  0.052632  0.051293  0.051293
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, this is indeed not that strange. For a small *y*, it holds that *y ≈* log *(1+y)*. See for more information [this *Mathematics Exchange* post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111041/showing-y%E2%89%88x-for-small-x-if-y-logx1).

A percentage change is calculated as *x<sub>i+1</sub>/x<sub>i</sub>-1*, whereas you calculate log(*x<sub>i+1</sub>/x<sub>i</sub>*). If we thus substitute *y* for *y = x<sub>i+1</sub>/x<sub>i</sub>-1*, we see the approximation pop up.